# Assert return NULL with MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Test class:

```cs
public class PlantDataControllerTests
{
    private Mock<PlantDataService> serviceStub = new Mock<PlantDataService>();
    private Mock<ILogger<PlantDataController>> loggerStub = new Mock<ILogger<PlantDataController>>();
    private PlantDataController controller;

    public PlantDataControllerTests()
    {
        serviceStub = new Mock<PlantDataService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        serviceStub.Setup(service => service.GetItemAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((PlantData)null);

        loggerStub = new Mock<ILogger<PlantDataController>>();

        controller = new PlantDataController(serviceStub.Object, loggerStub.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetItemAsync_WithExisitingItem_ReturnsExpectedItem()
    {

        var expectedItem = CreateRandomPlantData();

        serviceStub.Setup(service => service.GetItemAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expectedItem);

        var result = await controller.GetItemAsync(expectedItem.Id);

        result.Value.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedItem, opt => opt.ComparingByMembers<PlantData>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetItemAsync_WithExisitingItemByTopic_ReturnsExpectedItem()
    {
        //Arrange
        var expectedItems = new[] { CreateRandomPlantData(), CreateRandomPlantData(), CreateRandomPlantData() };

        serviceStub.Setup(s => s.GetItemsFromTopicAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(expectedItems.ToList());
        //Act
        var actualItems = await controller.GetItemsFromTopicAsync("plant/soilHumidity/2");

        //Assert
        actualItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedItems, opt => opt.ComparingByMembers<PlantData>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetItemsAsync_WithExisitingItems_ReturnsAllItems()
    {

        var expectedItems = new[] {CreateRandomPlantData(), CreateRandomPlantData(), CreateRandomPlantData()};

        serviceStub.Setup(s => s.GetItemsAsync()).ReturnsAsync(expectedItems.ToList());

        var actualItems = await controller.GetItemsAsync();

        actualItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedItems, opt => opt.ComparingByMembers<PlantData>());
    }

    private PlantData CreateRandomPlantData() 
    {
        return new()
        {
            Id = "60ae78fd9afed8cbe0b30336",
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
            Topic = "plant/soilHumidity/2",
            Value = new Random().Next(0, 3000)
        };
    }    
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
[ApiController]
public class PlantDataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PlantDataService plantDataService;

    private readonly ILogger<PlantDataController> logger;

    public PlantDataController(PlantDataService plantDataService, ILogger<PlantDataController> logger)
    {
        this.plantDataService = plantDataService;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PlantDataDto>>> GetItemsAsync() 
    {
        var plantData = (await plantDataService.GetItemsAsync()).Select(p => p.AsDto());

        var plantDataDtos = plantData.ToList();
        logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}: Retrieved {plantDataDtos.ToList()}");

        return Ok(plantDataDtos);
    }

    [HttpGet("{topic}", Name = "GetPlantDataFromTopic")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PlantDataDto>>> GetItemsFromTopicAsync(string topic)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic))
            return NotFound();
        var plantData = (await plantDataService.GetItemsFromTopicAsync(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(topic))).Select(p => p.AsDto());

        var plantDataDtos = plantData.ToList();
        logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}: Retrieved {plantDataDtos.ToList()}");

        return Ok(plantDataDtos);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}", Name = "GetPlantData")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<PlantDataDto>> GetItemAsync(string id)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            return NotFound(); 

        var plantData = await plantDataService.GetItemAsync(id);

        if (plantData is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}: Retrieved plantdata: {plantData.Id}");

        return Ok(plantData.AsDto());
    }
}
```

Service:

```cs
public class PlantDataService : IPlantDataService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<PlantData> _plants;

    public PlantDataService(IPlantStarterDatabaseSettings settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

        _plants = database.GetCollection<PlantData>(settings.PlantStarterCollectionName);
    }
    public PlantDataService()
    {

    }

    public virtual async Task<List<PlantData>> GetItemsAsync() => await _plants.Find(plant => true).ToListAsync();

    public virtual async Task<PlantData> GetItemAsync(string id) => await _plants.Find(p => p.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    public virtual async Task<List<PlantData>> GetItemsFromTopicAsync(string topic) => await _plants.FindAsync(p => p.Topic == topic).Result.ToListAsync();
}
```

AsDto method:

```cs
public static class DtoExtensions
{
    public static PlantDataDto AsDto(this PlantData plantdata) 
    {
        return new()
        {
            Id = plantdata.Id,
            TimeStamp = plantdata.TimeStamp,
            Topic = plantdata.Topic,
            Value = plantdata.Value
        };
    }
}
```

Every assert result returns null.

[image: unit test]

I do not really know what goes wrong here...

The test all went green until some point i changed the *Value* from `int` to `double`, but that seems very strange that is the cause of my unit tests failing because the calls itself just works in swagger and Postman.

Comment: You don't need `serviceStub.Setup` in constructor of test class.

Comment: You have shared with us a lots of unrelated code. Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please pick a single Controller Action (`GetItemsFromTopicAsync`) and the related test (`GetItemAsync_WithExisitingItemByTopic_ReturnsExpectedItem`). Every other method is just noise which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: BTW, you can call `serviceStub.Verify(s => s.GetItemsFromTopicAsync(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once)` to make sure that mocked method has been called.

Comment: When i use the verify it still returns this `Expected result.Value to be PlantData { Id = 60ae78fd9afed8cbe0b30336, Topic = plant/soilHumidity/2, TimeStamp = 05/08/2021 18:01:02, Value = 2446 }, but found <null>.`

Comment: Verify does not amend the setup. On the other hand it can be used to verify that the mocked method has been called. So, it works like a Spy object. I suggest to call that instead of your assertion to exclude that you have a mock setup problem.